# Hibernate Criteria: How to retrieve table data with foreign key relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria, criteria-api, detachedcriteria

I have two pojo classes wihch are named Document and DocumentUser. DocumentUser has an property documentId which linked to Document's id by foreign key.
So i want to create criteria query which retrieve Documents with its DocumentUser which is linked itself by forein key("document_id")

pojo classes:

Document

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@Entity
@Table(name = "DYS_BYS_DOSYA")
@Audited
public class Document implements Serializable {

    private Long id;
    private String name;

    private List<DocumentUser> documentUserList = new ArrayList<DocumentUser>();

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false, precision = 15, scale = 0)
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "AD", nullable = false, length = 500)
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "document", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    @Cascade(CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<DocumentUser> getDocumentUserList() {
        return documentUserList;
    }

    public void setDocumentUserList(List<DocumentUser> documentUserList) {
        this.documentUserList = documentUserList;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "tr.com.enlil.dys.server.servis.model.Document[id=" + id + "]";
    }
}
```

DocumentUser:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@Entity
@Table(name = "DYS_DOSYA_SAHIBI_USER")
@Audited
public class DocumentUser implements Serializable {


    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6393919788296838129L;

    private Long id;
    private Long personelId;
    private Document document;

    private String personelName;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false, precision = 15, scale = 0)
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "OLUSTURUCU_PERSONEL_ID")
    public Long getPersonelId() {
        return personelId;
    }

    public void setPersonelId(Long personelId) {
        this.personelId = personelId;
    }

    @Column(name = "KULLANICI_AD")
    public String getPersonelName() {
        return personelName;
    }

    public void setPersonelName(String personelName) {
        this.personelName = personelName;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "DOSYA_ID")
    public Document getDocument() {
        return document;
    }

    public void setDocument(Document document) {
        this.document = document;
    }
}
```

In this way, how can i get Document data depends on personelId of DocumentUser table by using criteria query? I am not familiar with hibernate and i need your helps. I try to write some codes but didn't work.

```
public List<Document> fetchRecordsByCriteriaLimitedList(String userId) throws Exception{
        Criteria criteria = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Dosya.class);

        DetachedCriteria dosyaSahibiCriteria = (DetachedCriteria) criteria.createCriteria("documentUserList");
        dosyaSahibiCriteria.add(Restrictions.eq("personelId", userId));
        dosyaSahibiCriteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);

            return criteria.list();

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several problems with your code. First of all, you said

> 2)DocumentUser is subclass of Document

This isn't true, judging from your code (it would mean that `DocumentUser extends Document`), but you probably meant they are in a parent -> child relation. Second, in `documentUserList` mapping, there is this `@OneToMany(mappedBy = "dosya", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)`, which means there is a field named `dosya` in `DocumentUser`, and there isn't. Instead, replace it with `mappedBy = "document"`. Assuming everything else is ok, query to get all documents based on their DocumentUser's id would be

```
public List<Document> fetchRecordsByCriteriaLimitedList(String userId) throws Exception{
    Criteria criteria = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Document.class);
    criteria.createAlias("documentUserList", "users").add(Restrictions.eq("users.personelId", userId));
    return criteria.list();
}
```

Comment: I transled my code to english and i forgot to changed it. And you are right, i tried to talk about parent-child relation by saying "subclass". It's my mistake too. Sorry. Let me edit them.

Comment: @angaraeski I understand, then it all looks OK. Does query from my answer work?